# Custom buffering of php mysql results - strange issue

Tags: php, arrays, loops, memory, mysqli

I discovered something very strange with my PHP code and mysqli functions. When I have my code in the format below:

```
function mainline(){
$q=mysqli_query($this->conn,"select * from table",MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
$dataset=parse($q);
}

function parse($q){
if (!$q){return NULL;}
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){$r[]=$res;}
mysqli_free_result($q);$q=NULL;$res=NULL;return $r;
}
```

I'm able to retrieve data and process it. In the above example, data is returned to `$dataset` and each element is retrieved in the form of `$dataset[row number][field name]`.

Now when I change my code so its like this:

```
function mainline(){
$q=mysqli_query($this->conn,"select * from table",MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
$dataset=parse($q);
}

function parse($q){
if (!$q){return NULL;}
while($r[]=mysqli_fetch_array($q)); // I made change here
mysqli_free_result($q);$q=NULL;return $r;
}
```

The data returned is always nothing even though the select statement is exactly the same and always returns rows. During both tests, nothing has modified the data in the database.

My question then is why does `while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){$r[]=$res;}` retrieve correct results and `while($r[]=mysqli_fetch_array($q));` does not?

With the second while loop, I won't have to allocate an extra variable and I'm trying to cut down on the use of system memory so that I can run more apache processes on my system instead of waste memory unnecessarily on PHP.

Any ideas why `while($r[]=mysqli_fetch_array($q));` wont work? or any ideas how I can make it work without using an extra variable? or am I stuck?

Comment: I see no point of doing this 

    while($r[]=mysqli_fetch_array($q));

Comment: My program stores the results in a multi-dimensional array for quick access later. and I need a loop to collect all data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store all result in array than why not use

```
mysqli_fetch_all($q)
```

and store result in whatever you want. Though if you want to have quick access I
 think caching sounds more appropriate.

> [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) — Fetches all result rows as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

Comment: Ok, so I did replace my while loop with `$r=mysqli_fetch_all($q);` and that does not seem to work even though the function you suggests makes sense. I begin to wonder if php has some bugs in its own code.

Comment: Oh. I am using unbuffered mysql queries and I just read on the php site: "...Also, mysqli_fetch_all works only for buffered result sets, which are the default for mysqli_query..."

Comment: sorry I was bit busy i ll get to you soon, meeting with boss

Comment: @Mike do you still need help on that? is this answer solving your problem if not then i will delete it